# Admob, Adsense Address (PIN) verification problem

Tags: android, admob, adsense

No ads showing in my android app since long time and in my admob console there is a card written on it:

> **Your ad serving is disabled**
> Your ad units are not serving ads in your app(s) and you’re not being paid. This is because you haven't verified your payment address. Please contact support to verify your payment address.

After I followed the steps in the contact support, it is required to request a replacement PIN

and the steps for requesting a replacement PIN are:

> 1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
> 2. **On your AdSense homepage**, find the PIN verification card and click Verify. (You might need to click View more to reveal the card.)
> 3. ...

The problem is when I open my Adsense home page, there is nothing except this message asking me to upgrade to Adsense to display ads on my site.

How do I solve this problem ?[image]

Comment: I've same issue.

Did you resolved the issue. Let m know if you can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add payment method.

Second, you may need to provide your tax information in AdMob depending on your country.

Third, verify the account holder's personal identity at Google Pay.

Finally, the PIN card will be available in Google AdSense under the payments option/tab.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - no PIN verification card on dahboard in AdMob. And the solution was to login to adsense account (https://adsense.google.com) and verify PIN there.

Comment: There is no PIN verification card there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the tip to try Google Adsense and didn't need to create a website. From what I've seen, the Admob account links with the Google Adsense account, which makes it easier.
With that, I was able to resend my PIN, so I'm currently waiting for it to arrive.

So

1- Click on Apply now

2- I didn't need to create a website, so just click "I don't have a website" and proceed. If for some reason it doesn't work and you need to create a website, try the following link for free: https://www.000webhost.com/)

3- Enter your Email, Then click Ok

4- At the top of the page you open will be in red, very small, a warning about blocking ads due to lack of verification. Click on "Action" below

5 -Scroll down to verify your payment address

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem... the help page says

> On your AdSense homepage, find the PIN verification card and click
> Verify. (You might need to click View more to reveal the card.)

...but there is no "Verify" button!

[image]

PS: My address is correct on the Profile page, and I only have the following Payment Method:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that it's tied to a (different) specific Payment Method?

Comment: Is this an answer?  *The only thing I can think of is that it's tied to a (different) specific Payment Method?* sort of sounds like an answer, but can you confirm whether inconsistent payment methods may be causing the querents problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Make sure you´re looking at the AdSense dashboard, not the AdMob one. The verify payment option should be under Payments -> Verification check.